# Engineering symbols

Tags: symbols, packages, engineering

Is there a package for engineering symbols like this or something similar? (forget the trucks, I need something simpler)

[image]

Comment: Just checking ... I think that none of these images has a Unicode ID.

Comment: Chemplants is a bit like this, the resit is `tikz `. https://mirror.marwan.ma/ctan/graphics/pgf/contrib/chemplants/chemplants-doc.pdf

Comment: Nice! Thank you very much!